# Why is Make not injecting this variable value in my recipe?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider my Makefile recipe

```
build:
    export TAG=main; docker build my_dir -t my-image:$(TAG)
```

I expected `$(TAG)` to be replaced with "main", but it's the blank string. I've also tried `$$TAG` and `$(shell echo $TAG)`, but none of them cause Make to inject "main" as I expected.

Comment: `... my-image:$$TAG` works as expected for me -- assuming I've understood the problem correctly.

Comment: `$$TAG` does seem to work.  I tried it but must have been fooled by another error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `export TAG=main` sets (and unnecessarily exports) a *shell* variable.  Your `$(TAG)` attempts to expand a *`make`* variable.  These are not the same thing.

There are at least two possible solutions:

- convert `TAG` to a `make` variable

  ```
  TAG = main

  # ...

  build:
          docker build my_dir -t my-image:'$(TAG)'
  ```
- or expand `TAG` as a shell variable

  ```
  build:
          TAG=main; docker build my_dir -t my-image:"$${TAG}"
  ```

The former would be cleaner and more natural unless you have some need for `TAG` to be an environment variable other than what is apparent in your example.

Notes:

- To `make`, both `$(variable)` and `${variable}` expand to the value of variable `variable`, including in recipes, but to the shell, those forms mean different things.
- To pass a `$` through to the shell -- to get the shell to perform a variable expansion, for example -- it needs to be escaped by doubling it.
- `make` allows whitespace around the `=` in a variable assignment, but the shell does not.
- You should quote shell variable expansions with double quotes.  You can also quote make variable expansions in recipes with either single or double quotes, and often this is a good idea.  The quotes are meaningless to `make`, but appropriate for protecting the expansion from further interpretation by the shell.